# Is there a way to attach a file that was created as a blob in the browser to an email

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

I know that you can attach a local file to an email by embedding its direct path in the url. Is there a way to do something similar with a file that was created in the browser as a blob? This is created as part of some javascript code that i'm running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using an *XMLHttpRequest* to submit your data. Rather than simply *POSTing* the email body, you can create a [*FormData*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) which you *POST* to the server instead.

Say you have a file you want to upload called `myBlob`, and some other email-relevant strings, you could do

```
var data = new FormData();
//           name       , value     [,  filename       ]
data.append('attachment', myBlob     , 'myFileName.txt');
data.append('to'        , emailText                    );
data.append('subject'   , subjectText                  );
data.append('body'      , bodyText                     );
```

Then on the final step of your *XMLHttpRequest* (say called `xhr`) you send `data`

```
xhr.send(data);
```

Now you access these in your server side code with (for example in php) `$_POST` as usual.

Web browser support is [IE10+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal what do you mean "save as file"? If you just want to offer the client a download you can skip the whole sending to server and just do `URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)` and set as a _href_ on an `<a>` with a _download_ attribute.

Comment: That's actually not what I meant, but is independently very useful! Thanks! What I originally was looking for is a way to attach a file to an email from a local mail client like Outlook or Thunderbird. When you click a mailto: link, it can be opened by a mail program. Can the same link encode an attachment?

Comment: @user1094206 I'm pretty sure that the standard _mailto_ protocol does not support attachments for security reasons; any implementations which permit it would be non-standard (such as outlook 2003).